# What generic icon could be used to symbolize a brand (McDonalds, Apple, etc..)?

Tags: icon, symbolism

I need to use an icon in a web application that will represent "Brand" as an object. The "Brand" could be "McDonalds", "Apple", "BMW" or any other company/brand.

What generic icon would represent "Brand" well?

Right now we use a simple star as a brand icon, but we are not quite happy with this.

Any suggestions?

Comment: @Dom I don't think how what this question is trying to ask--it's asking about how to represent the concept 'your brand', rather than asking how to make a brand logo.

Comment: @Dom I'm swedish, and my english is not the best :) I was looking for recommendations, not how-to-tutorials!

Comment: Hi user3449608, I hope you don't mind but I edited your question a bit to make it more clear. If you feel my edit was incorrect, please click the [edit](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/posts/48981/edit) link and change it as you feel is needed. Welcome!

Comment: Is the icon supposed to look like it _could be a_ logo, or just symbolize a "brand object" in the same way that an icon of a key symbolizes a primary key object in a database manager? Because one obvious possibility for the latter would be an icon of a physical cattle brand. EDIT: I see someone else already suggested it.

Comment: I'm not against the question, but it does seem to fit into our 'brainstorming' bucket.

Comment: @DA01 I see it along the same lines as the save as icon or push/pull questions - brainstorming to a degree but still overly beneficial in the long run. Just my 2¢ though.

Answer (score 18):

I'd recommend not using a star, as stars are very often used for "favourites" lists or to mark the current content as a favourite.

It sounds like you're trying to create something that looks like a generic brand logo, like an icon for brands and logos in general. This is tricky because you're looking for something that is common to logos - when logos deliberately *don't* look alike.

There are however some things that are common to logos you could use to make a generic mark logo-like:

- `TM` [trademark symbol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trademark_symbol)
- `®` [registered trademark symbol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Registered_trademark_symbol) (be warned though that in some countries it is apparently illegal to use this when something has not been registered as a trademark)
- [bold Helvetica text with tight kerning](http://www.carsonshold.com/2012/09/50-helvetica-logo/)
- generic geometric shapes like overlapping circles

A few top of the head examples:

[image]

Comment: I agree with this option, except for the generic circles... master card, rgb model? and I would use the ® instead of that B.

Comment: It's a (B) instead of an ® since using an ® for something that's not a genuine registered trademark is illegal in some countries. The two circles probably is a bit too close to Mastercard... it's just an example.

Comment: Yeap, I mean I would use only the (R) alone, without any previus symbol.

Comment: Ah! Yeah, that's a pretty good suggestion. Why not suggest it as an answer?

Answer (score 6):

Of course, you could always use an image of an actual branding iron (there some good ones on the internet which could be adapted for use as an icon). After all, the modern day "brand" came to us from the practice of branding goods with branding irons to establish ownership.

Who knows? The idea might eventually catch on!